# Macro Recursion in Jinja2

Tags: python, recursion, jinja2

I'm using Jinja 2.8 templating engine.  I'm trying to write a template which will walk over a tree structure and output information from that tree.  To do this I'm trying to use a macro which calls itself which doesn't seem to work.

This simple recursive macro also doesn't work:

```
{% macro factorial(n) %}
  {% if n > 1 %}
    {{ n }} * {{ factorial(n-1) }}
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}

{{ factorial(3) }}
```

When run following error is raised on the third line of Jinja code.

```
UndefinedError: 'factorial' is undefined
```

Does Jinja support recursive macros?  How else could a nested data-structure be traversed in Jinja?

Comment: Its generally a bad idea to do computation operations on a template. If you have a specific situation where recursion is needed please explain that. Factorial is better done in the controller rather than the template

Comment: Agreed, but as mentioned above the factorial is just a simple recursion example which doesn't work.  I want to recursively walk a tree structure presented to the template and output the the relevant parts.
Also note that the factorial example output is not a computation, but a presentation of a calculation.  The output above would be "3 * 2".

Comment: I just ran your code in Python 3.5 + Jinja2 2.8 and got the expected output.  What Python + Jinja2 version are you using?

Comment: I have no idea why do you have that error, but for recursively walk a tree structure, I suggest you to use `for ... recursive` and `loop` instead "real" recursion macro calling.

Answer (score 11):

Jinja supports recursive macros.
Regarding the factorial code, the following code works for me:

```
{% macro factorial(n,return_value) -%}
--{{n}}
  {%- if n > 1 -%}
    {%- set return_value = n * return_value %}      {#- perform operations on the variable return_value and send it to next stage -#}
    {{- factorial(n-1,return_value) -}}

  {%- else -%}      {# Output the return value at base case #}
    {{ return_value }}
  {%- endif %}

{%- endmacro %}

{{ factorial(7,1) }}
```

The output I got is

```
--7--6--5--4--3--2--1  
    5040
```

Comment: I've pasted this code in and I'm still getting UndefinedError: 'factorial' is undefined.  What version of Jinja are you using?  Run python -c "print __import__('jinja2').__version__"

Comment: I was using an older version of Jinja. But I think the macro functionality hasn't changed with respect to recursion.
python -c "import jinja2; print jinja2.__version__"
2.2.1

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue, and noticed my macro definition was sitting in an `if` block, which means it won't be there if the `if` evaluates to false.

But it did not work when I moved the definition just above the `if` blocks - I had to move it above my `{% block content %}` before I could get it to work.

I would suggest your code might be sitting nested amongst some other code that will be preventing it from being found.